# Polymer "property-changed" event not fired when element property is set

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, custom-element

I have a Polymer element (`cw-app`) property declared like this:

```
test: {
  type: String,
  notify: true,
  value: 'default test value'
}
```

As you can see it has a declared default value of `default test value`.

Initially, when the element is added to the page like this: `<cw-app></cw-app>` a corresponding `test-changed` event is being fired.

However, if I add the element and set a value for the property like this: `<cw-app test="new value"></cw-app>`, then no `test-changed` event is being fired initially.

Is this a desired behavior and has it been documented anywhere?

http://jsbin.com/xazaqozani/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's the expected behaviour:

- In the first case the value of `test` is changed from `null` (no `test` attribute set) to `"default test value"` so the *changed* event is fired.
- In the second case the value is set to `"new value"` at creation time. It's not changed so there's no *changed* event.

See a discussion on [Polymer issue page](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3605#issuecomment-213088319) on GitHub:

> If you declare `<x-foo id="foo" value="foo"></x-foo>` the value foo will be assumed to be coming 'from above', t.i. from a user of the element. During config phase Polymer will not echo such data changes upwards. (Assuming the producer of the value/user of the element already has knowledge of this change.)
>
> On the other side, if you `<x-foo id="bar"></x-foo>` the default value
>   will propagate upwards. For the same reasons, x-foo produced this
>   value, and the user of x-foo has otherwise no knowledge about this.
>   T.i. the default value is not coming from above(, but from x-foo).

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer, you can upvote if ot helped :-)